# Get list of ALL customers using REST API

Tags: api, rest-api, webapi

I know I can get a specific customer by running:
curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:32769/index.php/rest/V1/customers/2" -H "Authorization: Bearer token"
How do I get the list of ALL customers?.. 
GET "http://127.0.0.1:32769/index.php/rest/V1/customers" produces "{"message":"Request does not match any route.","trace":null}"

Comment: what is the Magento version you are using?

Answer (score 5):

Try following

```
curl -X GET -g "http://127.0.0.1:32769/index.php/rest/V1/customers/search?searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=email&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=asc" -H "Authorization: Bearer token"
```

Rest API reference http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html