# Magento2 REST API get all customers details

Tags: magento2, customer, rest-api

```
 public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    }  


public function  getAllCustomers() {         
            $customerCollection = $this->_customerFactory->create();
            return $customerCollection;
        }
```

Im getting following error:

> {
>       "message": "Invalid parameter configuration provided for $reader argument of Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList",
>       "trace": "#0 /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array,
>   'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'reader', 'Magento\\Framewo...')\n#1
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Framewo...',
>   Array, Array)\n#2
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Framewo...',
>   Array, Array)\n#3
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')\n#4
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(42):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')\n#5
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/generated/code/Magento/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Set/Interceptor.php(13):
>   Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set\Interceptor->___init()\n#6
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111):
>   Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set\Interceptor->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Model\Context),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Registry),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Eav\Model\Config),
>   Object(Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\GroupFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AttributeFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Interceptor),
>   NULL, NULL, Array)\n#7
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Eav\\Mod...',
>   Array)\n#8
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Eav\\Mod...')\n#9
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\\Eav\\Mod...')\n#10
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Eav\\Mod...')\n#11
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\\Eav\\Mod...')\n#12
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Custome...',
>   Array)\n#13
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/framework/Validator/UniversalFactory.php(36):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Custome...',
>   Array)\n#14
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php(229):
>   Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory->create('Magento\\Custome...')\n#15
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/ResourceModel/Customer/Collection.php(87):
>   Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection->_init('Magento\\Custome...',
>   'Magento\\Custome...')\n#16
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php(164):
>   Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection->_construct()\n#17
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/VersionControl/AbstractCollection.php(60):
>   Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategy\Query),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy),
>   Object(Magento\Eav\Model\Config),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Interceptor),
>   Object(Magento\Eav\Model\EntityFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Helper),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory), NULL)\n#18
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/ResourceModel/Customer/Collection.php(76):
>   Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\VersionControl\AbstractCollection->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategy\Query),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy),
>   Object(Magento\Eav\Model\Config),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Interceptor),
>   Object(Magento\Eav\Model\EntityFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Helper),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\Snapshot),
>   NULL)\n#19
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111):
>   Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategy\Query),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy),
>   Object(Magento\Eav\Model\Config),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Interceptor),
>   Object(Magento\Eav\Model\EntityFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Helper),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\Snapshot),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy\Config), NULL,
>   'Magento\\Custome...')\n#20
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Custome...',
>   Array)\n#21
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Custome...',
>   Array)\n#22
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/generated/code/Magento/Customer/Model/ResourceModel/Customer/CollectionFactory.php(43):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('\\Magento\\Custom...',
>   Array)\n#23
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/app/code/Soulof/CustomerAttribute/Model/Account.php(117):
>   Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory->create()\n#24
>   [internal function]:
>   Soulof\CustomerAttribute\Model\Account->getAllCustomers()\n#25
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#26
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(244):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Proxy))\n#27
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#28
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array)\n#29
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#30
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, Array)\n#31
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#32
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#33
>   /var/www/html/dreamb2b/index.php(39):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))\n#34
>   {main}" }

Answer (score 0):

Seems ,you have done wrong.

Magento2, already have rest API point, you do not create any API point like controller action. Check out Magento 2 rest API https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/bk-rest.html

If you want to get all customer list then use  API pint `rest/V1/customers/`
Checkout all point  a swagger: https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/

Check out this answer also

[Get list of ALL customers using REST API](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/171679/get-list-of-all-customers-using-rest-api)

Comment: Hi Bera, i know about the Customer api call, i want to customized fields and based customer i need other data also. please let me know what was the issue or any other method get customer data

Comment: What you mean by  customized fields?